# When creating a object of custom type I'm losing a field variable

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm currently creating a program in which I'm trying to create a pointer to a class called Member, from inside a class called Tour.

For the creation of the pointer I do like this:

```
    void Tour::initiateMember()
{
    this->sizeOfArrParticipants = 5;
    ptr = new Member*[sizeOfArrParticipants];

}
```

But when I later try to use the ptr varible I noticed that it hasn't created all the fields correctly. The member class has three field, two strings and a int, and the two strings are created but the integer is never created instead when you debugg it says that "it cannot ready memory".

Here is the some short example of the code:

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member();
    Member(string name, int memberNr, string phoneNr);
    ~Member();

    void setName(string name);
    void setPhoneNr(string phoneNr);
    void setMemberNr(int memberNr);

private:
    string name;
    string phoneNr;
    int memberNumber;
};


Member::Member()
{
    this->name = "Joe Doe";
    this->memberNumber = 0;
    this->phoneNr = "0";
}

Member::Member(string name, int memberNr, string phoneNr)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->memberNumber = memberNr;
    this->phoneNr = phoneNr;
}

Member::~Member()
{
}

void Member::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

void Member::setPhoneNr(string phoneNr)
{
    this->phoneNr = phoneNr;
}

void Member::setMemberNr(int memberNr)
{
    this->memberNumber = memberNr;
}

string Member::getName() const
{
    return this->name;
}

string Member::getPhoneNr() const
{
    return this->phoneNr;
}

int Member::getMemberNr() const
{
    return this->memberNumber;
}


class Tour
{
public:
    Tour();
    Tour(int date, string name, int eduLevel, int typeOfTour, int participants);
    ~Tour();

    void initiateMember();
    void addParticipant(int memberNr, string name, string phoneNr);

private:
    int date;
    int participants;
    int typeOfTour;
    Member **ptr;
};



Tour::Tour()
{
    this->date = 0;
    this->typeOfTour = 0;
    this->participants = 0;
    this->initiateMember();
}

Tour::Tour(int date, string name, int eduLevel, const int typeOfTour, int participants)
{
    this->date = date;
    this->typeOfTour = 0;
    this->participants = participants;
    this->initiateMember();

}


Tour::~Tour()
{

}

void Tour::initiateMember()
{
    this->sizeOfArrParticipants = 5;
    ptr = new Member*[sizeOfArrParticipants];
    Member ptr2;
    ptr2 = Member::Member();
    Member obj1;
    obj1.setMemberNr(1);

}

void Tour::addParticipant(int memberNr, string name, string phoneNr)
{
    ptr[0]->setMemberNr(memberNr);
    ptr[0]->setName(name);
    ptr[0]->setPhoneNr(phoneNr);

}

int main()
{
Tour tourB();
tourA.addParticipant(1111, "Stina Larsson", "011-111111");
return 0;
}
```

Now when I have been trying more noticed that it works if I use the default constructor to create a object of the Member class.

```
Member ptr2;
ptr2 = Member::Member();
```

Then all fields are created and accessible, why can't I do this with the array of pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "the integer is never created"? Can you please elaborate? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: where is the main you ran ? and `ptr = new Member*[sizeOfArrParticipants];`, an array of pointer ? really ? you should prefer using vector.

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun I can't use a vector for this assignment. We have tu use an array of pointers.

I can put in the little main function also

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when I check with the debugger after I created the array of pointer it says "unable to read memory" on the integer called memberNumber.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` notation; access members directly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thought that was the convention?

Comment: @anderssinho it is, but in Java, not in C++.

Comment: @Quentin okay, but that's not the root of my problem

Comment: You have the member variable `Tour::ptr`, but you never make it point anywhere. It is uninitialized and *indeterminate*. Dereferencing it (like you do in `addParticipant`) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so when I do  ptr = new Member*[sizeOfArrParticipants]; inside addParticipants, I don't point it to that part of the memory you mean?

Comment: But you don't do that in the code you show!

Comment: *Also* you use `participants  - 1` as the index. This is a problem because when you call it the first time then `participants` is equal to zero, and you will use `-1` as the index. Which will be out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited the code again.It should say that the index is 0 just for this test. And in the initiateMember I think I do the pointing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167273/discussion-between-anderssinho-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: Okay now you allocate some memory for `ptr`, but e.g. `ptr[0]` is still not a valid pointer. It doesn't point anywhere specific. It's still *indeterminate*. Perhaps you should have an array of *objects* instead of an array of pointers to objects? I.e. `Member* ptr;`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have now reworked the initiateMember and it looks like this:

Member *memberArr = new Member[5];
ptr = &memberArr;
ptr[0]->setName("hej");

And now I can assign values to the variables with the pointer. But I think there most be a more neat way to do this?